# Creating a form to input multiple contacts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm trying to devise a form that will allow me to input multiple contacts.  It's a pretty long form so far and I want to keep it as short as possible.  I was thinking of just having one set of fields for contact inputting which will add this contact to a list box or gridview but I'm not sure that is the most elegant solution.  Could anyone else point me in the right direction to something good I can use?

I'm writing in HTML / asp.net / javascript.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the way Facebook does this in their new message popup. If you have an account, try creating a message and adding multiple contacts to the "To" box. Basically it's a big box with a list of contacts you've added. At the end is an inline borderless textbox to add the next contact. Clicking anywhere in the field focuses the hidden textbox at the end. At least that's how I think it works... If you decide you like it, maybe take a closer look at it using Firebug for Firefox. I'm not suggesting ripping off their code or anything, I just think it would be a good starting point for what your talking about.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your message.  I'm not sure that will really fit into what I want to do.  I don't think I've explained it correctly.

It's a booking system I'm developing and I need to get information on the different people going on the course.  It could be up to ten people per booking and I need to get their forename, surname, tel no and email.  I could just put 10 individual contacts to fill in but that would look terrible.  I was hoping to devise a way of using Javascript and JQuery to add a contact to the form after the previous one has been filled out.  Not sure if it's possible though